# Making an iframe editable

Tags: angularjs, html, iframe

I am using angularjs for my application. In that i am loading a text file from url(ng-src) to iframe and displaying the content in iframe. But i want to make some changes in the loaded text file, which is loaded to iframe. 
Here is my HTML code.

```
<div style="padding-left: 0px;" class="col-sm-5 text-center">
    <iframe id="content" ng-src="{{$scope.files.url}}" width="100%" height="400" align="middle"></iframe>
</div>
```

And here is my angularjs part, file source.

```
    $scope.files = {

    1 : {
        "id" : 1,
        "name" : "0066030.txt",
        "url" : "http://demo/textFiles/0066030.txt"
    },

    2 : {
        "id" : 2,
        "name" : "0101907.txt",
        "url" : "http://demo/textFiles/0101907.txt"
    },
    3 : {
        "id" : 3,
        "name" : "0124757.txt",
        "url" : "http://demo/textFiles/0124757.txt"
    }
};
```

I am successfully loading the text file content. Can any one please help me in make it editable. 
If any other HTML tags are there (example: textarea, .. etc) for loading text files using ng-src attribute, thats also fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Editing of `<iframe>` elements is restricted by [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy). This is to prevent evil websites from tricking users with Cross-Origin Content.

For an `<iframe>` element that can be edited without restrictions:

```
<iframe src='about:blank'>
</iframe>
```

This means content needs to be downloaded and an `<iframe>` element built with DOM manipulation techniques.

> ### Same-origin policy
>
> The same-origin policy restricts how a document or script loaded from one origin can interact with a resource from another origin. It is a critical security mechanism for isolating potentially malicious documents.
>
> [— MDN Developer Reference - Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)

> ### `<iframe>` Attributes
>
> - **src**
>     The URL of the page to embed. Use ['about:blank'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy#Inherited_origins) for empty pages that conform to Same-Origin Policy.
>
> [— MDN HTML Reference - `<iframe>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)

Comment: HI @georgeawg, thanks for explanation. It was helpful. Can u please guide me, any other ways to load text files in a editable mode. For example , textarea...

Comment: See [MDN Web Developer Guide - Making Web Content Editable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content). Also consider using the [UI Tinymce - AngularJS directive for the Tiny Moxie Content Editor.](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-tinymce).